# Why my Objective-C object doesn't want to be instantiated?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, initialization

I've got a problem (in Objective-C/iPhone dev) since more than one week, so I'd be really grateful if someone can help me out.

When I instantiate an object from a class that I've written, it returns me nil, but when I launch the debug mode I actually see in the *init* method that the attributes of self are correctly initialized and it seems like it doesn't execute the return self instruction.

EDIT:

Thanks for your answers Here is the init code

```
-(id)initWithDate:(NSString *)aDate
             type:(NSString *)aType
           amount:(NSString *)anAmount
         currency:(NSString *)aCurrency
     merchantName:(NSString *)aMerchant
           status:(NSString *)aStatus
{
    if (!(self = [super init])) return nil;
    self->date=aDate;
    self->type=aType;
    self->amount=anAmount;
    self->currency=aCurrency;
    self->merchantName=aMerchant;
    self->status=aStatus;
    return self;
}
```

Comment: Please, post your init method's code.

Comment: Thanks for your answers 
Here is the init code 

-(id)initWithDate:(NSString *)aDate type:(NSString *)aType amount:(NSString *)anAmount currency:(NSString *)aCurrency merchantName:(NSString *)aMerchant status:(NSString *)aStatus
{
 if (!(self = [super init]))
  return nil;
 self->date=aDate;
 self->type=aType;
 self->amount=anAmount;
 self->currency=aCurrency;
 self->merchantName=aMerchant;
 self->status=aStatus;
 
 return self;
}

Comment: Please post the code you're using to check if the returned object is nil (I'm suspecting you're wrong by saying *When I instantiate an object from a class that I've written, it returns me nil* or you're using alloc/init incorrectly - because the code you posted looks fine)

Answer (score 1):

I'd put your code inside the following

`if (self = [super init]) {
        // Custom initialization
    }
    return self;`

rather than the if (!(self... return nil you have used. But that's just a habit.

I would also avoid the C++ style '->' assignments and instead use self.currency=aCurrency; (or [self setCurrency:aCurrency]; which is closer to the c++ calls I guess) assuming these are declared as @property or have getters and setters.

I'm sure one of those will get you going!

Comment: `self.currency` only works if `currency` has been declared as an `@property` (or if he has a `setCurrency` method).

Comment: Actually, using `if (!(self = [super init])) return nil;` gets rid of the whole-method-long `if` instruction which I personally despise. I use this method too :)

Comment: I thought the c++ -> was a method caller and required the same thing. My mistake.

Comment: Now I've thought about it, I agree Adam.

Comment: Also, Wil Shipley's take on initializer form is worth reading: http://www.wilshipley.com/blog/2005/07/self-stupid-init.html

Answer (score 1):

Don't use `self->instanceVariable`.

Just use `instanceVariable`.

Answer (score 0):

You should write

```
self.date = aDate;
// etc....
```

if `date` etc. is declared as a `@property` in the `@interface`, or if it's just a class instance variable, use

```
date = aDate;
// etc...
```

Also, if the strings are not declared as `@property` with `retain` or `copy` modifiers, you'll need to manually `retain` them thus:

```
date = [aDate retain];
```

Comment: Thanks. But I don't think this is the actual problem, even though every attribut is a property. Actually, I just wrote it with -> to avoid the properties mechanisme to trigger, for performance reasons. May be i'm completely wrong since I'm in Objective-C only for one month... :)

Comment: "to avoid the properties mechanisme to trigger, for performance reasons" - trying to optimize something prematurely is one of the **worst** possible errors people do to increase performance... Using properties (with their `retain`/`copy`/`assign` types) lets it easier to manage memory correcly in Objective-C - I strongly suggest you use it, and optimise performance only after you've established where your real bottlenecks are.

Comment: just use date=aDate to avoid triggering the setters. However, you will start to leak if you are not very careful.